# all solutions so far don't allow installation of VBox on 2020 Mac OSX Monterey

Tags: macos, virtualbox, installation

I have spent several hours on 2 occasions trying to install VBox on a 2020 Macbook Air MacOS X without success. My attempts were 1 month apart and included:

1. on OS Big Sur
2. after updating to Monterey 12.0.1

I had previously posted this and did not receive a reply:   https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20598#comment:1

I tried the following:

1. from a terminal:    sudo kextcache --clear-staging   (coupled with deleting install from Applications, running uninstall script from installer, restarting computer, did multiple times)
2. opening in Recovery mode, then:    spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963
3. in Recovery disabling SIP by:    csrutil disable    (side note: now I can't re-enable SIP, first it won't connect to the usual Wifi, then once connected to a different Wifi I get a message about "personalization settings error")
4. I have tried to install the following versions of VBox with SIP disabled:
   6.1.30 -- won't even start install, says I don't have the right computer (error is: you need AMD64 for this to work)
   6.1.28 and 6.1.26 -- install error, no opportunity in Security & Privacy to add Oracle
   When I try the install of 6.1.28 or 6.1.26 with SIP disabled I got a little further, but then get a dialog that says "System Extension Blocked -- A program tried to load new system extension signed by "Oracle" that need to be updated by the developer."  Needless to say I'm monitoring Security & Privacy for the chance to allow Oracle and it doesn't come up (it only comes up when I run the uninstall script).
   Does anyone have a solution outside of 1 through 4 above?

Comment: I presume you are installing version of VirtualBox designed to work with ARM hardware?  The error you have received indicates that might not be the case.  I don't believe you can run VirtualBox, on an Apple ARM M1 processor, and install a x86 operating system at this time.

Comment: The VBox should work on the hardware, 6.1.30 must have a bug with hardware detection (6.1.28 or 6.1.26 don't have this bug). It is a 2020 M1 Mac. As for the operating system to use in virtual box -- I cannot get far enough to install the Windows7 for emulation that I have ready to go (I have Vbox installed on a Win10 computer emulating 64bit Win7 -- so those Win7 files are ready to go). I have installed Vbox on several older Macs (and then ran Win7) and this is the first I've encountered so many problems.

Comment: Your older Macs had x86 processors so it wasn't an issue to run VirtualBox on them and install an x86 operating system  If you believe it's a software bug you should downgrade.  However, I have not read anything about VirtualBox being able to virtualized x86 hardware on any Apple ARM hardware.  I only know one hypervisor that has that feature at this time.

Comment: @Wojciech Szerminski just to be clear VirtualBox is NOT an emulator. It runs x86 or x86_64 code natively, trapping certain code which needs to be redefined. If your laptop is Arm based,  then it will NOT work.

Comment: I have installed Vbox on 64bit Macs previously. Once installed I will try to run 64bit Windows7 -- however I'm not at the stage where Vbox itself is installed and I get to add an operating system to emulate

Comment: I have only now realized the ARM processors are completely different than Intel 64bit processors. I guess Vbox 6.1.28 has a bug that attempts the install on OS X?

Comment: VBox has no ARM build & none has been announced. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422565/does-virtualbox-run-on-apple-silicon